relation between eigenvectors of the diagonal matrix and its perturbation
Let $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right)$. Assume that $B=AR_{\theta}$, where $R_{\theta}$ is an irrational rotation. Is it true that eigenvectors of $B$ are rotated by $\theta$ and then scaled? One more question, can we say $B$ is in the open neighborhood $A$ (in the uniform topology)? In other words, I want to say that if you perturb $A$, then you can obtain $B$.
Attempt: The rotation matrix $R_{\theta}$ rotates any vector by an angle $\theta$. So, if we apply $ R_{\theta}$ to the eigenvectors of $A$, we get rotated versions of those eigenvectors.
The matrix $A$ scales its eigenvectors by their corresponding eigenvalues. For example, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is scaled by 2, and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is scaled by $\frac{1}{2}$.
Comment after the answer: In general, is there any relation between eigenvectors of $B$ and $A$? For instance, they are close to each other for a small angle

Augmenting the previous answers to address your follow-up question,

Yes, in general as long as the original matrix has all distinct eigenvalues, under small continuous changes of the entries of the matrix, the eigenvalues and their associated eigenvectors  will change by small continuous amounts. This is a consequence of the fact that the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix change continuously under small variations in its coefficients (provided the roots remain all distinct)

In your case of a 2x2 matrix there is additional geometric structure to your problem that allows us to visualize it more concretely in direct physical terms. The following geometric discussion is an alternative to the more abstract algebraic treatment alluded to previously.


If $\lambda$ and the nonzero vector $X$ are real,
the eigenvalue condition $BX=\lambda X$ means that $X$ and $BX$ are parallel. If you take $X$ to be normalized to have length 1 in the plane, writing it as some unknown point on the unit circle as $X=<\cos t, \sin t>$ then   the  vector $N(t)=<-\sin t, \cos t>$ is orthogonal to $X$. The eigenvector condition requires that the projection of $BX$ onto  $N$ must vanish (because $N\cdot BX = N\cdot (\lambda X)=\lambda  (N\cdot X )=0$.
When you expand the equation $f(t)=N(t) \cdot BX(t) =0$ in terms of trig functions in the variable $t$, and exploit the double angle formula for squares and products of sines and cosines, you  get a periodic function on the unit circle of frequency $2$ whose period is $\pi$ (rather than $2\pi$). It has the format
$f(t) = A_1 \cos(2t) + A_2 \sin(2t) + A_3$ Equivalently you can write $f(t)= R\cos(2t+\phi)+ A_3$ where the total amplitude $R$ and  phase shift $\phi$ are explicit functions of $A_1$ and $A_2$. The zeros of this function $f(t)$ determine the location of the eigenvectors. When you make small perturbations in the entries of $B$, the amplitude coefficients in this trig function change by small amounts. The  location and number of  zeros of this function  therefore  change only by small amounts.  In fact the number of solutions only disappears when $|A_3|$ exceeds $R$.; and for strictly smaller values $|A_3|<R$ there are generally 2 pairs of antipodal solutions on the unit circle.
In your numerical example, the formula for $B= R_{\theta} A$ actually corresponds to rotating $N$ by $\theta$,  changing $N(t)$ to $N(t+\theta)$. This is a very explicit type of perturbation of $f(t)$.
You can plot graphs of $f(t)$ yourself to see how the zeros change.

Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I have one more question : Assume that we have two matrices $A$ and $C$ in SL (2) that they two distance  eigenvalues and their eignevctors are not in the same direktions. Can we find small irrational angle $\theta$ such that eigenvectors $AR_{\theta}^n$ $CR_{\theta}^n$ are not the same direction?

Perhaps repost this as a separate question. What is the significance of superscript $n$?. Is it a power.? And do mean $ A R^n$ should have eigenvectors distinct in their directions from those of $C R^n$ for all $n$,or some $n$? Or do you mean the four-fold product should have eigenvectors distinct from $A$ and $C$?

Yes! It is power. $AR^n$ should have eigenvectors distinct in their directions from those of $CR^n$ for all $n$ and their eigenvectors are distinct from $A$ and $C$?

It's true that if you multiply an eigenvector of $A$ by $R$, you get a rotated version of that eigenvector.  But that new vector is very unlikely to be an eigenvector of $B$. As an example, suppose we take $\theta = 0.1$ (about 6 degree angle). Then we have (I'm copying Matlab output and editing slightly):
A =
2.0000         0
     0    0.5000

R =
0.9988   -0.0500
0.0500    0.9988

B =
1.9975   -0.1000
0.0250    0.4994

Applying $R$ to the first eigenvector of $A$ (namely $\pmatrix{1\\0}$) gets us
u =
0.9988
0.0500

and $B$ times this is
Bu =
1.9900
0.0499

which is not a multiple of $u$, so $u$ is not an eigenvector.
That's really no surprise. Calling the eigenvectors of $A$ by the names $e_1$ and $e_2$, and using $c$ and $s$ for the sine and cosine of the selected angle, you were asking whether $Re_1$ is an eigenvector of $B$. Let's compute. First, $Re_1$ is just the first column of $R$, namely
$$
Re_1 = \pmatrix{c\\s}
$$
Now let's look at $B$ times that
\begin{align}
B (Re_1) 
&= B (c e_1 + s e_2)\\ 
&= RA (c e_1 + s e_2)\\ 
&= c (RA e_1) + s (RAe_2)\\
&= c (R2e_1) + s (R\frac12 e_2)\\  
&= 2c Re_1 + \frac{s}{2} Re_2 \\
&= 2c (ce_1 + s e_2) + \frac{s}{2} (-se_1 + ce_2) \\
&= 2c^2 e_1 + 2cs e_2 - \frac{s^2}{2} e_1 + \frac{cs}{2} e_2 \\
&= (2c^2 - \frac{s^2}{2} )e_1 + (2cs + \frac{cs}{2}) e_2 \\
&= (2c^2 - \frac{s^2}{2} )e_1 + \frac{5cs}{2} e_2 \\
\end{align}
That's not a multiple of $Re_1$, so $Re_1$ is not an eigenvector.

Thank you very much for your answer.  In general, is there any relation between eigenvectors of $B$ and $A$? For instance, they are close to each other for the small angle

Sort of. If the eigenvalues are distinct, then for small enough angles, you should get  "nearby eigenvectors". Look at that last line: if $s$ is tiny, then $e_1$ is almost an eigenvector, so something near it probably IS an eigenvector. On the other hand, if $A$ is something like the identity (i.e., equal eigenvalues), then $RA$ will actually have complex eigenvalues (namely $s$ and $c$, hence no real eigenvectors at all, while $A$ itself will have every nonzero vector as an eigenvector.
